# How to stop scrolling simulation of the scroll view when the content dimension is changed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have prepared a simple application with a horizontally scrollable container. The scrolling simulation is applied when I changed the content dimension of the scrollable container after the scroll position is reached to the `maxScrollExtend` position.

I asked the flutter community about this. They told that this is the expected behavior of the scrolling. But, I need to restrict the scrolling simulation.

Please, anyone, let me know the workaround of how to restrict the scrolling simulation or how to customize the scrolling without the simulation behavior.

**Replication procedure:**

1. Run the below simple sample.
2. Scroll fully in the horizontal direction and reach the end.
3. Tap the floating button to change the size at runtime.

**Code Snippet:**

```dart
class ScrollingSimulationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  NestedDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrollingSimulationDemoState createState() => _ScrollingSimulationDemoState();
}

class _ScrollingSimulationDemoState extends State<ScrollingSimulationDemo> {
  double width = 500;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
          height: 350,
          width: width,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          width = 250.0;
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To check the GitHub issue for this behavior, refer to the following link,
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86711